# pdo count not working

Tags: sql, pdo

I have a page and all the function is working my only problem now is ciunying the record from the databse..

Class.user.php

```
Public function data($count)
{
 $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login");
 $result=$this->db->prepare($count);
 $result->execute();
 $number_of_rows=$result->fetchColumn();
 }
```

Index.php

```
<table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>2014</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
       <?php
           $count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login";
      $crud->data($count);
        ?>
```

The problem is that its not showing the count..

Comment: `SELCT` and `CIUNT` are both misspelled in your `index.php`. Your function is bizarre and doesn't make sense - why are you preparing two different statements, executing only one?

Comment: Im sorry fir that its just a typo

Comment: You're neither outputting nor returning the count value at any point. So, yeah, the count won't be displayed.

Comment: @deceze can you help me please.im trying different ways but no luck..

Answer (score 2):

1. You're writing the same query as function argument, but also inside the function itself. And you're only really using one. This is nonsense. Dedicate your method to return the count, don't make the query a parameter.
2. `prepare`ing the statement is pointless in this case, since you're neither reusing it nor are you binding any values. You can simply `query()` it directly.
3. The clincher: **you're neither outputting nor returning the count**, so it's very very expected that it doesn't show up anywhere.

Here's a sane version:

```
public function getCount() {
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login');
    return $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $crud->getCount(); ?>
```

Comment: I already your code and its working now..but i tried my query something like this select count(user_id) as id, sum(user_id) as area from login

Comment: But the problem with that is that it only echoes the ciunt not the sum.

Comment: @kier Well, that's because you haven't taken the time to understand anything about what's going on. You need to take a basic PDO tutorial and then use your brain. Your code calls `getColumn`. Passing it a query that fetches two columns won't make the code magically return more than that one column.

Answer (score -3):

I think I usually do it like this [link](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/2012/10/16/pdo-cheatsheet/)

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row =$stmt->fetchObject();
```

then to output it you would have to ECHO

```
<table>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <?php echo $row['count'];?>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```